# “Such” as a pronoun and “Reduction Transformations”

Tags: grammar, pronouns, universal-grammar, transformations

I just ran into this in the novel "Pride and Prejudice"

> -"Ah! you do not know what I suffer."
>   -"But I hope you will get over it, and live to see many young men of four thousand a year come into the neighbourhood.''
>   -``*It will be no use to us if twenty such should come, since you will not visit them.*''

1. The occurrence of "such" here is interesting to me. Is it a pronoun here which is brought instead of "young men of four thousand a year"?
2. What is the deep structure of the noun phrase of the if-clause? the surface structure is "twenty such". Is the deep structure "twenty young men who are of 4 thousand a year"?
3. When a Reduction Transformation is possible which is better to be used? for example, is it better to say "a man who is of large fortune" or "a man of large fortune"? Any links elaborating on the Reduction Transformations in English would be truly appreciated. As far as I know, there are six RTs. But I need a trustworthy reference for my further studying.

Comment: Welcome to the site! 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. I see no reason to add "who is", but I don't know about "reduction transformations".

Comment: @user43947 It seems likely to me that your example involves NP-ellipsis of *men* following *such*, given that *twenty such men* is independently attested. An ellipsis analysis allows us to give a uniform analysis of *such*, rather than analysing it as ambiguous between a pronoun and some sort of determiner. The underlying representation for your example would be: *It will be no use to us if [twenty such <[NP men]>]...*. Incidentally, does *reduction transformation* mean the same thing as *ellipsis*? I'm not so familiar with the older transformational terminology.

Comment: _Ellipsis_ is classic terminology and non-specific as to source, effect, or context. _Reduction_ and _deletion_ are terms used in several varieties of generative syntax, generally as names of specific rules that can be argued to represent deletions (or gaps, or empty nodes, or many other terms).

Comment: Generally what is missing is either repeated material in one way or another ([Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), [Equi-NP-Deletion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf)),  indefinite NP arguments, like the subjects of the gerunds in _Seeing is believing_, or predictable meaningless syntactic particles, like [_Whiz_-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299).